# NodeJS, using MongoDB Native driver, how do I convert ObjectID to string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using MongoDB native driver for NodeJS, and am having trouble converting `ObjectID` to a `string`.

My code looks like:

```
db.collection('user', function(err, collection) {
  collection.insert(data, {safe:true}, function(err, result) { 
    var myid = result._id.toString();
    console.log(myid);
  )};
});
```

I have tried various suggestions on StackOverflow like:

```
myid = result._id.toString();
myid = result._id.toHexString();
```

but none of them seemed to work.

I am trying to convert the `ObjectID` to `base64` encoding.

Not sure if I am running into supported functionality under the Mongo native driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`insert` returns an array of results (as you can also send an array of objects to be inserted), so your code is trying to get the `_id` from the array instance rather than the first result:

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb", function(err, db) {
    db.collection("user").insert({name:'wiredprairie'}, function(err, result) {
        if (result && result.length > 0) {
            var myid = result[0]._id.toString();
            console.log(myid);
        }
    });
});
```

Also, you won't need to base64 encode the result of calling `toString` on an `ObjectId` as it's returned as a hex number already. You could also call: `result[0]._id.toHexString()` to get the Hex value directly (`toString` just wraps `toHexString`).

Answer (score 7):

This work for me:

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var idString = '4e4e1638c85e808431000003';
var idObj = new ObjectID(idString);

console.log(idObj);
console.log(idObj.toString());
console.log(idObj.toHexString());
```

Output:

```
4e4e1638c85e808431000003
4e4e1638c85e808431000003
4e4e1638c85e808431000003
```

Comment: Thank you, both of these examples have been very helpful